# Multi-character character constant [-Wmultichar] Error in C

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-construction, character

```
#include <stdio.h>
main ()
{
    int c;
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF ) {
        if (c == '\t') {
            while ((c = getchar()) == '\t');
                putchar ('\\t');
        }
        else (c == '\b') {
            while ((c = getchar()) == '\b');
                putchar ("\\b");
        }
        else (c == '\\' ) {
            while ((c = getchar()) == '\\');
                putchar ("\\");
        }
        putchar(c);
    }
}
```

I get the following error when trying to compile:

> cpytbb.c: In function ‘main’:
>   cpytbb.c:8:14: warning: multi-charactercharacter constant [-Wmultichar]
>   cpytbb.c:10:20: error: expected‘;’ before ‘{’ token

Please note that the second error is probably irrelevant to the issue. I'm new and I most likely have done some mistakes in my code.

In case it's needed, I'm using gcc.

Edit: I'm trying 'print' out \t \b and \ as simple text. As an example if I hit 'backspace' it will print \b

Comment: Replace `'\\t'` with `'\t'` and `'\\b'` with `'\b'`. Also make sure you give `putchar()` a `char` argument instead of a whole string ...

Comment: Also `putchar()` takes an int, not a char*: `putchar ("\\b")` <- wrong.  You want `'\b'` (single, not double quotes).

Comment: Alright, thank you both.
goldilocks Does that mean that putting double quotes changes an int to a char* ( I don't even know what a char* is, googling it atm)

Comment: Is `putchar ('\\t');` intended to print a backslash followed by a `'t'`, or just a tab?

Comment: It's intended to print \t as a string and not tab

Comment: @EQP: Googling for `char*` isn't likely to be useful; searches for punctuation don't work well. A `char*` is a pointer to `char`. An array of `char` *decays* to a pointer to its first element in most contexts.

Comment: @KeithThompson I suppose I'll pass learning about it now, pointers are few chapters in the book.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Several issues:

1. Use of putchar() to try and print more than one character. A backslash is a character, so is a `b`, or a `t`.
2. Use of different quotes on the call to `putchar()`. Single quotes are for single characters (an escape sequence like `\b` expands to a single character, so is OK, whereas `\\b` is an escape sequence for a backslash followed by *another* character), double quotes are for strings (i.e. a series of zero or more characters ended by a zero-value character (`\0`).
3. Even if you fix those, your program will be wrong, because you have a semicolon after your while loop. This means that you have an empty loop (it just performs an "empty statement" each time through the loop) and then after that loop it calls `putchar` exactly once.
4. Two `else` blocks, with conditions. `else` can not have a condition. You're probably looking to write `else if( ... )` instead.

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues with your code.

First off, you should be using `puts`, not `putchar` - `putchar` is meant for printing a single character, whereas it looks like you want to print multiple characters.

Second, the issue is with the line `putchar ('\\t')`. Those should be double quotes, not single quotes. The other `putchar` statements are correct (as far as quotation is concerned).

Third, assuming you want your code to print out escaped sequences (i.e. a tab character causes a backslash and t to be printed), the string in `putchar ("\\")` should be `"\\\\"`. As a rule of thumb, to print `N` backslashes, you'll need `2N` backslashes in your string.

If, however, you want to actually print the original character (i.e. a tab character input causes a tab character to be printed), you'll need to instead keep the `putchar` calls, but get rid of the double backslashes and replace the double quotes with single quotes.

Finally, your indentation suggests that the `putchar` calls should be inside the `while` loops, but you have a semicolon at the end of each `while` statement. This means the `putchar` calls are *not* part of the `while` loop. If this is not intended, remove those semicolons.

Perhaps editing your post clarifying what exactly you're trying to accomplish would be beneficial.